# How to populate a div on click with jQuery, AJAX & CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to populate a DIV with a table. The table needs to be styled and the styling has to be done in the controller and then passed to the AJAX request as a HTML snippet to be displayed in the result DIV. I am running to multiple issues with the implementation. Below is the code and summary. I am asking you to tell me what I should add to the `generate_suggestions` function to get it working.

**How I've done it before in the view**

```
  <table>
    <!-- Function that splits the array in $pages into the first 5 movie suggestions -->
    <?php foreach ($pages->result() as $row): ?>
      <a style="display:block" href="<?php echo base_url('core/detail/'.$row->id) ?>">
        <div id="suggested" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">
          <div id="info">  
              <p><b><?php echo $row->name ?></b></p>
          </div>
          <div class="details">
                <p><?php echo $row->summary ?></p>
          </div>
        </div    
      </a>    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </table>
```

This is how I styled the array of rows before. So basically what I need is to somehow fit this styling into the `controller` and then pass it to the request so it can display the results already styled.

**Controller**

```
public function generate_suggestions($start = 0, $count = 5) {

    $movies = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM movies LIMIT ' . $start . ',' . $count);
    //Here I need to put the code that styles the contents of the array so it gets properly displayed in the div
```

On the first load I take the 1st 5 movies from my DB. Now I need to style the rows into table and send the table back to the request.

**View**

```
<div id="listB"></div>

</script><script type="text/javascript">
    var nextstart = 6;
    var movies_per_page = 5;

    $( "#next_btn" ).click(function() {

        $.get("core/generate_suggestions/"+nextstart+"/" + movies_per_page,
        function(data) {

            $( "#listB" ).html(data);

            nextstart += movies_per_page; 
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
```

In the view for some reason I need to insert the script at the end of the `body`. When I put it in the head nothing ever happens when I click the `next_btn` div. The script calls the `generate_suggestions` function from my `controller` and then displays the result in div `listB`

Thank you all for reading and your help. I am really clueless.

Comment: please check wheather your are getting the paramters from the view to the function as your using the $.get() method you should use $post()

Comment: I need to get something from the function. I just don't know how to pass it to the $get.. should it be in an `echo` or what, that is what I am trying to figure out

Comment: echo $movies and alert in the script on the view page ....

Comment: how do I do the alert please? does it belong into here `function(data) {            $( "#listB" ).html(data);

            nextstart += movies_per_page; 
        });`

Comment: function(data) {</br>
                   alert(data);<br/>
            $( "#listB" ).html(data);<br/>
            nextstart += movies_per_page; <br/>
        });<br/>

Comment: well. we got a problem :D The alart is full of my code for `main_view.php` how is that possible???

Comment: I'm just gonna shorten it. But the way it works I have a main page. There I click on SEARCH button which opens the 2nd page and displays the first 5 movies. The `view` for the main page has for example this in the `body = <input type="submit" id="nav_btn" name="whatever" value="Log In!">` and ton of other stuff. Now when I click the `next_btn` on my 2nd page it puts the `body` of my main page in to the div `listB` that makes no sense

Comment: cant visualize your output

Comment: Before I click the `next_btn` the div `listB` is empty. When I click the button the `listB` has `<input type="submit" id="nav_btn" name="whatever" value="Log In!">` inside of it. When it should have the `echo $pages` inside..

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add some information from server using JQuery, you could use an easy way with the JQuery method called load()

Example:

$( "#next_btn" ).load( "core/generate_suggestions/"+nextstart+"/" + movies_per_page );

more info: http://api.jquery.com/load/

In CodeIgniter, the controller should call generate_suggestions, and with the data returned (movies) you have to call a view and insert them. The view should contain your html+php.Like:

$data['movies'] = $movies->result();
$this->load->view("yourview", $data);

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Comment: yeah but I need to know in to what I should enclose the data I am trying to pass back to the request.